# Not responding problem when using print on tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am new on python tkinter developing . i made tools that scan url list using request get when i try to filter them and insert on textbox it show not responding and then after lot of time it insert on textbox where is then problem

i have tired lot of method and watch python tkinter tutorial but not found tutorial

````
import requests
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool                            
from time import time as timer  
from random import sample as rand
from Queue import Queue                     
from platform import system
from urlparse import urlparse
from optparse import OptionParser   
from colorama import Fore                               
from colorama import Style                              
from pprint import pprint                               
from colorama import init                                               
init(autoreset=True)


####### Colors   ###### 

fr  =   Fore.RED                                            
fc  =   Fore.CYAN                                           
fw  =   Fore.WHITE                                          
fg  =   Fore.GREEN                                          
sd  =   Style.DIM                                           
sn  =   Style.NORMAL                                        
sb  =   Style.BRIGHT                                        

#######################

RaiC0d3r = Tk()
RaiC0d3r.title("CMS Detector V.1 ")
RaiC0d3r.geometry("1920x1080")

def cmsdetector():
    ipv4check = requests.get('http://ipv4.icanhazip.com').text
    licensed = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raic0d3r/Private-Bot/master/licensed').text
    if ipv4check in licensed:
        try:
            Get_list = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = (("txt files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
            with open(Get_list, 'r') as zz:
                Readlist = zz.read().splitlines()
        except IOError:
            print '--------------------------------------------'
            print '    [-] List Not Found in Directory!'
            sys.exit()
        thread = []
        for url in Readlist:
            url = url 
            t = threading.Thread(target=sitebul, args=(url, ''))
            t.daemon = True        
            t.start()
            thread.append(t)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        for j in thread:
            j.join()
    else:
        PrintWpData.insert(END, 'Ask Permission From RaiC0d3r')
        PrintJMData.insert(END, 'Ask Permission From RaiC0d3r')
        PrintDpData.insert(END, 'Ask Permission From RaiC0d3r')
        PrintPsData.insert(END, 'Ask Permission From RaiC0d3r')
        PrintOsCData.insert(END, 'Ask Permission From RaiC0d3r')
        PrintZenData.insert(END, 'Ask Permission From RaiC0d3r')
        PrintunkData.insert(END, 'Ask Permission From RaiC0d3r')

#    concurrent = 75
#    q = Queue(concurrent * 2)
#    for i in range(concurrent):
#        t = threading.Thread(target=sitebul)
#        t.daemon = True
#        t.start()
#    try:
#        for url in open(Get_list):
#            q.put(url.strip())
#        q.join()
#    except:
#        pass

def sitebul(url, x):
    try:
#        while True:
#            url = self.q.get()
#            if url.startswith('http://'):
#                url = url.replace('http://', '')
#            elif url.startswith("https://"):
#                url = url.replace('https://', '')
#            else:
#                pass
#            try:
        Checktwo = requests.get('http://'+url, timeout=5)
        CheckOsc2 = requests.get('http://'+url + '/admin/login.php', timeout=5)
        Checktree = requests.get('http://'+url + '/application/configs/application.ini', timeout=5)
        if "/wp-content/" in Checktwo.content:
            PrintWpData.insert(END, url+'\n')
#            PrintWpData.see(END, url+'\n')
#            PrintWpData.update_idletasks(END, url+'\n')            
        elif requests.get('http://'+url + "/administrator/manifests/files/joomla.xml").status_code == 200:
            PrintJMData.insert(END, url+'\n')
        elif "/sites/default/" in Checktwo.content:
            PrintDpData.insert(END, url+'\n')
        elif "prestashop" in Checktwo.content:
            PrintPsData.insert(END, url+'\n')
        elif "osCommerce" in CheckOsc2.content:
            PrintOsCData.insert(END, url+'\n')
        elif "APPLICATION_PATH" in Checktree.content:
            PrintZenData.insert(END, url+'\n')
        else:
            PrintunkData.insert(END, url+'\n')
        #    except:
         #       pass
    except:
        pass                

domain = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="Domain :")
domain.grid(row=2,column=0)

domainEnt = Button(RaiC0d3r , text="Domain List",bg="purple" , fg="white" ,command=cmsdetector)
domainEnt.grid(row=2 ,column=4)

#progress = Progressbar(RaiC0d3r, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=200,  mode='determinate')
#progress.grid(row=2,column=3)

#ProxyPrint = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="Proxy :")
#ProxyPrint.grid(row=0,column=0)

#EntProxy = Entry(RaiC0d3r)
#EntProxy.grid(row=0,column=1)

#domainEnt = Entry(RaiC0d3r)
#domainEnt.grid(row=0,column=1)


#Bts = Button(RaiC0d3r , text="Get",bg="purple" , fg="white" ,command=openfile)
#Bts.grid(row=0 ,column=5)

Space = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="      ")
Space.grid(row=2,column=2)

wp = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="Wordpress      ")
wp.grid(row=4,column=1)

joomla = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="Joomla      ")
joomla.grid(row=4,column=2)

drupla = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="Drupal      ")
drupla.grid(row=4,column=3)

pshop = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="PrestaShop      ")
pshop.grid(row=4,column=4)

oSCmr = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="osCommerce      ")
oSCmr.grid(row=4,column=5)

zen = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="Zen      ")
zen.grid(row=4,column=6)

unk = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="Unknown      ")
unk.grid(row=4,column=7)

URL = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="CMS     :")
URL.grid(row=5,column=0)

PrintWpData = Text(RaiC0d3r , width=30 , height=40,wrap=WORD)
PrintWpData.grid(row=5 , column=1)

PrintJMData = Text(RaiC0d3r , width=30 , height=40,wrap=WORD)
PrintJMData.grid(row=5 , column=2)

PrintDpData = Text(RaiC0d3r , width=30 , height=40,wrap=WORD)
PrintDpData.grid(row=5 , column=3)

PrintPsData = Text(RaiC0d3r , width=30 , height=40,wrap=WORD)
PrintPsData.grid(row=5 , column=4)

PrintOsCData = Text(RaiC0d3r , width=30 , height=40,wrap=WORD)
PrintOsCData.grid(row=5 , column=5)

PrintZenData = Text(RaiC0d3r , width=30 , height=40,wrap=WORD)
PrintZenData.grid(row=5 , column=6)

PrintunkData = Text(RaiC0d3r , width=30 , height=40,wrap=WORD)
PrintunkData.grid(row=5 , column=7)


Space = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="      ")
Space.grid(row=6,column=2)

Space = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="      ")
Space.grid(row=7,column=2)

copyright = Label(RaiC0d3r, text="CMS Detector BY RaiC0d3r")
copyright.grid(row=8,column=4)

def selectall(event):
    event.widget.tag_add("sel","1.0","end")

RaiC0d3r.bind_class("Text","<Control-a>", selectall)
```RaiC0d3r.mainloop()

result show on textbox but take time and show no responding https://prnt.sc/ovs07r
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Python 3.6.5 under windows10 so there may be some differencies.

I took the liberty of reducing your code to a managable size and then I inserted a few prints of the current time, to see where the time is consumed.

```
import requests
from tkinter import *                     
from datetime import datetime


def cmsdetector():
    print(datetime.now())
    ipv4check = requests.get('http://ipv4.icanhazip.com').text
    print(datetime.now())
    licensed = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raic0d3r/Private-Bot/master/licensed').text
    print(datetime.now())
    if ipv4check in licensed:
        PrintWpData.insert(END, 'ipv4check passed')
    else:
        PrintWpData.insert(END, 'Ask Permission From RaiC0d3r')
    print(datetime.now())


RaiC0d3r = Tk()

domainEnt = Button(RaiC0d3r , text="Domain List", command=cmsdetector)
domainEnt.grid(row=2 ,column=1, pady=(10,0))

PrintWpData = Text(RaiC0d3r , width=30, height=10, wrap=WORD)
PrintWpData.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

The output when I click the **Domain List** button was:

```
2019-08-22 03:09:08.418965
2019-08-22 03:09:08.496544
2019-08-22 03:09:08.922195
2019-08-22 03:09:08.922195
```

where you can see that the most time is consumed by the `requests.get()` calls. So I'd guess that the load on the servers you are interrogating may vary and may sometimes be "a lot of time". From what I can see there is no problem with tkinter.

Comment: yah but i know reason that is it scann all list then sametime inseart to textbox but why it not inseart single domain

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i mean if i use PrintWpData.insert(END, url) then it take time to show result on PrintWpData = Text(RaiC0d3r , width=30, height=10, wrap=WORD) but i i use print url it print on cmd too fast